# Object and Arrays: Change object property with reference to second object (chart.js example)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am playing around with chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org). Currently I have a line graph based on the below object. X-axis data is populated from array stored as 'x' in below example. I have two datasets which are the two lines shown on my graph. The Y-axis data is stored as 'y' and 'z' in the below example.

I am trying to add some functionality where a user can show only a particular line or both if they'd like.

In other words, add or remove an  object instance within the dataset property.

My understanding of the below structure: The whole thing is an object named data; this has two properties called labels and datasets. The datasets property is an array of object instances. Is this a valid way of thinking about it?

```
var data = {

    labels : x,
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(222,223,179,0)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(222,223,179,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(222,223,179,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : y
        },

        {

            fillColor : "rgba(194,95,207,0)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(194,95,207,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(194,95,207,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : z
        },

    ]
}
```

I tried solving my problem by creating a dataSetReference object like below:

```
  dataSetReference = [
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(222,223,179,0)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(222,223,179,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(222,223,179,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : y
    },

    {

        fillColor : "rgba(194,95,207,0)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(194,95,207,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(194,95,207,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : z
    },

]
```

Then referencing it in my original data object like

```
   datasets: dataSetReference[0,1]
```

or just:

```
   datasets: dataSetReference[0]
```

This didn't work. Any suggestions on why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should know that **non primitive types** like **objects** and **arrays** are manipulated  by **their reference** let's take a simple example to demonstrate this  :

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a; // now b point to the same reference as the a does,meaning any modification to b will be applied to a also

// for example 
b.push(4);
console.log(a); // you will get  [1, 2, 3, 4] instead of [1, 2, 3] that we are expecting 

//so you can use  only :
datasets: dataSetReference


//and if you want to access separate items from dataSetReference you can use .slice() method 

   var tmpvar = dataSetReference.slice(0,3,4) // now tmpvar = dataSetReference[0,3,4]
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to hold the full selection of array elements somewhere then reference particular items in my datasets property? In my actual project, there are 8 datasets so don't want to list out separate objects for all the different combinations.

Comment: You don't want to store 8 datasets(array of objects) in the dataSetReference variable that's it  ?

Comment: I was thinking that would be a decent approach if I could reference only one or two of them when needed; your above example showed that wasn't possible though. Now its looking like I'd need an array of eight objects, an array of two objects, an array of three objects etc, and separate objects for when only one line is needed. Lots of lines of code.

Comment: you want to access separate items from the dataSetReference ?

Comment: the objects within dataSetReference represent 8 lines to be drawn on  a graph. Im going to setup some buttons which allow the user to display all lines or any combination of lines; yes separate items/combinations of the items in dataSetReference. That is why my initial approach was to try datasets: dataSetReference[0] or datasets: dataSetReference[0,3,4] etc. That didn't render the graph and your initial answer explained why. Not found an efficient solution yet though

Comment: using  dataSetReference[0,3,4] will return only dataSetReference[4] and if you want to use dataSetReference[0],dataSetReference[3] and dataSetReference[4] you can simply create a temporary variable `ie tmpvar = dataSetReference.slice(0,3,4)` which will return only dataSetReference[0 and 3 and 4]